# Stack lists under each other with cards

Tags: trello-lists

Is there a way you can stack lists under each other with their own lists in a column rather than run every list accoss the page?

Answer (score 4):

I developed the extension [List Layouts for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/list-layouts-for-trello/aldklnbenbdgfgfbflalmlddkkndgnlc) that allows you to toggle between displaying a Trello board's lists vertically, horizontally, or in a grid.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this with the plugin Stylish and some CSS tweaks.

Just add

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("trello.com") {

    .list {
       margin: 0 5px 13px 10px;
    }
    #board {
       flex-wrap: wrap;  
       overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

to a stylish Section and apply to URLS starting with https://trello.com

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you try and drag a list under another list it'll just snap back to it's original position.
Each card list is just that, a vertical list that will automatically grow to the height of your browser tab adding a scroll bar as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you fiddle with small-ish window size, Trello will suddenly switch between 2 or more alternative stacked views. The behavior currently is very unpredictable, unfortunately.